# Lock-down of cell references in the formulae of multiple cells concurrently in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to lock down cell references in the formulae of cells in an Excel table when the cells are processed as a group?  (The F4 key allows the lock-down of cell references only one cell as a time.)

Comment: It looks like F4 cycles through relative, absolute and mixed cell references *when you're editing a formula*, and applies to the currently-selected part of the formula or the single reference that the caret's on. If you've merely got a cell *selected*, it does nothing. Thus, it's natural that F4 can't do what you want, as you can't edit more than one formula at once. I know this isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use F4 to get the appropriate [mixed cell reference](https://blogs.office.com/2011/08/17/making-sense-of-dollar-signs-in-excel/). (I rarely find absolute cell references necessary.) Then, I fill down or across (or both) to get my column or my row to populated with the same formula. Or, depending on how my sheet is laid out, I copy and paste the cell instead of filling down/across.

Answer (score 0):

Bernie Deitrick at [this excelforum.com thread](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/571354-locking-multiple-cells-f4-key.html) gives the following macro, saying to **select your cells first**, then run it:

```
Sub ConvertToAbsoluteReferences()
Dim myCell As Range
Dim storedCalc As Variant
Dim RefStyle As Variant
Dim MyMsg As String
Dim myStyle As Integer

MyMsg = "1: =A1 Relative" & Chr(10) & _
"2: =A$1 Absolute Row" & Chr(10) & _
"3: =$A1 Absolute Column" & Chr(10) & _
"4: =$A$1 Absolute" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
"Choose a style: 1, 2, 3, or 4...."
myStyle = Application.InputBox(MyMsg, "Style Choice", , , , , , 1)

Select Case myStyle
Case 1
RefStyle = xlRelative
Case 2
RefStyle = xlAbsRowRelColumn
Case 3
RefStyle = xlRelRowAbsColumn
Case Else
RefStyle = xlAbsolute
End Select

With Application
storedCalc = .Calculation
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each myCell In Intersect(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
myCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula( _
myCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, RefStyle)
Next myCell

.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.Calculation = storedCalc
End With
```

It seems to work fine to me, in Office 2013. To run macros, first enable the Developer tab by customizing the ribbon, then checking the unchecked box in the right-hand column. You'll find Macros on that tab.

Two additional thoughts:

- when running macros, be aware of what the macros are doing, or have a competent person examine them for you. I won't be liable for macros compromising your data or your machine in unexpected ways; and
- I personally prefer the approach I suggest in my other answer. Such a macro seems a blunt instrument to me, although I can imagine scenarios in which it would be the more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

If they are all in the same row or column, you can just find and replace (looking in formula)  adding the `$ $` signs before and after the reference you want to lock.

```
EI. ='RATE CARD'!D5
```

Find `!D` and replace by `!$D$`

Comment: Welcome to [su]! This looks like a solid answer, but could use some formatting. You can the code block, and inline code buttons to surround text with code formatting. (Inline code blocks are typed like this: \`here is my text\` and look like this: `here is my text`